# Confused about how to install Rails plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I found an example [here](http://nubyonrails.com/articles/the-complete-guide-to-rails-plugins-part-i) showing how to install a Rails plugin. Their example shows this:

```
./script/plugin install calendar_helper
```

This won't work for me because, confusingly, I don't have anything called `plugin` in my `script` directory. All I have is `rails`:

```
$ ls script/
rails
```

So Rails doesn't come with the script you need to install plugins? You need a plugin to install plugins? That doesn't seem very likely. Is something wrong with my Rails project?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're probably on Rails 3. Replace ./script/plugin with rails plugin.

```
rails plugin install calendar_helper
```

But the other problem is plugins, unlike gems, need to be installed with a full path. This was also true in Rails 2.x.

```
rails plugin install https://github.com/topfunky/calendar_helper.git
```

Comment: P.S. You may or may not have problems with the calendar_helper plugin on Rails 3 though. The comments in https://github.com/topfunky/calendar_helper say it was last updated for Rails 2.2.3.

Comment: FWIW, after a couple years of using Rails, I've never done anything with plugins since I asked this question. It's all been gems.

Answer (score 0):

You should first input text like gem 'calendar_helper' in your Gemfile, and then run bundle install for rails 3.0

Comment: As per Andrei's comment below, and Brian's answer above, he is installing a plugin, not a gem.